# CSS Loading and Applying Problem in Local Host

Tags: html, css

***Note :** Solution has been appended to the answer at the bottom.*

Okay, I've been doing it all the time but now it doesn't work.

Here is my folder structure which is so simple :

```
+ root
|_ + styles
  |_ -main.css
|_ + images
  |_ - background.jpg
|_ - index.html
```

**Here is the html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Css Code :**

```
body
{

}
 div .main
{
    background-image:url(../images/main_background.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:950px;
    width:897px;
}
```

**The problem is :** css file doesn't seem to be loaded and there is no css styles applied to class name `main` on the html file. That's really frustrating. I've also put them under IIS creating an Application under.

What could be wrong?

Thanks.

**Solution:**

Since the both answer should be at the same place to solve my problem, I decided to put complete answer here:

1. It should have been `div.main`
2. and `<link href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the `rel` attribute for the `link` for your CSS file, like so:

```
<link href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: This answer is also correct but to solve the problem completely tjm's answer is also required -- http://goo.gl/sHIro

Answer (score 2):

I think `div .main` in the css should read `div.main`. Note the lack of space.

With the space you are specifying child elements of divs, where the child has class main, without the space you are specifying divs with the class main.

Comment: @Braveyard This is also true. To target a `div` with a class `main` you need to use `div.main` or just `.main`. Using `div .main` would look for a `div` that has a child element with a class `.main`.

Comment: I didn't know the space factor. Thanks.

Comment: This one is also true but I have only one option to mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the path from relative to absolute:

```
<link href="styles/main.css" type="text/css"/><!-- relative -->
<link href="/styles/main.css" type="text/css"/><!-- absolute -->
```